# Windows 10, disable raise-on-click

Tags: windows

I have been looking for this, without success ..

Is there a way to DISable raise-on-click on Windows? To be more specific, only raise a window when clicking on the title bar, but not when i click into the window (e.g. for drag-and-drop)?

Please no discussion whether this makes sense or not.